# cv2: HoughLinesPointSet fails in a simple example

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, point-clouds, hough-transform

I'm working on detecting lines in point clouds. For that manner, I wish to utilize the cv2 function [HoughLinesPointSet](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga9d621819105b32cf3dd97c4260c823db).

I obtained accurate results for the example in the documentation, but I am getting poor results for a rather simple study case, so I think I am missing something here.

I would be happy to hear any clarifications and/or suggestions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv2

# Study case
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y1 = np.zeros(10)
y2 = np.ones(10)

plt.scatter(x, y1)
plt.scatter(x, y2)

# Hough transform
pnts1 = np.column_stack((x, y1))
pnts2 = np.column_stack((x, y2))
pnts = np.row_stack((pnts2, pnts1))
pc = pnts.reshape(-1, 1, 2).astype(np.float32)
pc_lines = cv2.HoughLinesPointSet(pc, lines_max=20, threshold=5, min_rho=0, max_rho=20, 
                                  rho_step=1,min_theta=0, max_theta=np.pi, 
                                  theta_step=np.pi/100)

votes, rho, theta = pc_lines[:, 0][:, 0], pc_lines[:, 0][:, 1], pc_lines[:, 0][:, 2]

# Convert to cartesian
theta[theta == 0.] = 1e-5  # to avoid division by 0 in next line
a = -1 / np.tan(theta)  # the implied lines are perpendicular to theta
x = rho * np.cos(theta)
y = rho * np.sin(theta)
b = y - a * x

# Plot
xx = np.linspace(0, 10)
for (ia, ib) in zip(a, b):
    yy = xx * ia + ib
    plt.plot(xx, yy)

plt.show()
```

[image: Results of HoughLinesPointSet]

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. There does indeed seem to be an issue with the PointSet algorithm, as if you simply swap the `x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)` with `x = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 10)`, the method works just fine.
2. However, when the method works fine, there then appears to be an issue with your formulas for `a`, `x`* and `y`, as something feels off about the assumption that "lines are (implied to be) perpendicular to theta". Where in the documentation is that mentioned? If theta is indeed the direction of the line, rather than the direction of the normal vector, then the maths would need to reflect that.

* Note: it is bad practice to redefine `x` mid-way through your code